# use jquery to toggle class for 1 second every 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, css

How can I toggle the class for just 1 second, every 5 seconds?

This is the action I would like, just need to make it happen for 1 second, every 5 seconds..

```
$('#donate').toggleClass('wiggle');
```

Comment: Do you mean, continuously toggling the class for 1 second?

Comment: every 5 seconds, turn class on then 1 second later turn it off..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the following

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   // toggle the class every five second
   $('#donate').toggleClass('wiggle');  
   setTimeout(function(){
     // toggle back after 1 second
     $('#donate').toggleClass('wiggle');  
   },1000);

},5000);
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/vqRqf/