# Change DIV's class every X second but not just 1 but with multiple classes

Tags: jquery

I've seen this code already and know how it works

Link: [use jquery to toggle class for 1 second every 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147677/use-jquery-to-toggle-class-for-1-second-every-5-seconds)

But how would you do this with Multiple class?.

For example,

- first 5 second will add "CLASS1 "
- next 5 seconds will add " CLASS2  "
- and next 5 seconds would add " CLASS3 "
- and then repeat this after everything is done.

I only know little jQuery and still learning. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the class every `x` amount of seconds, you would use `setInterval`:

```
var counter = 1;
var int = setInterval(function(){
    $("div").attr("class", "class" + counter);
    if (counter === 3){
        counter = 1; // If counter = 3, set it back to 1 for next loop
    } else {
        counter++; // Else, add 1 to the counter
    }
}, 5000);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/p5ZGN/)

If you'd like to stop the function from running after `x` amount of iterations, you could set up a second counter, and then use `clearInterval(int)` to programmatically end it.

Comment: @Shiro I'm glad it worked, but do you understand *how* it works? It's much better to understand the code than just blindly use it (at least that's what I've learned).

Comment: Can't really say I actually understand the whole part. All I know right now is that in every 5 seconds "counter" adds +1 to it then apply it to the DIV. I'll study jQuery soon on CodeAcademy. But just needed to ask this cause I kinda need it right now. Thanks again @Charlie ! :D.

Answer (score 2):

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   // toggle the class every five second
   $('#donate').toggleClass('wiggle');  
   setTimeout(function(){
     // toggle back after 1 second
     $('#donate').toggleClass('wiggle');  
   },1000);
},5000);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/vqRqf/)**

Answer (score 0):

Another effort:

Demo: [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/pWgfG/2/)

JS

```
$(function(){
    var timer, i=1;
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        if (i > 3) i = 1;
        $('#addme').addClass("class"+i);
        $('#addme').append("<br>added class"+i);
        i++;
    }, 5000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="addme">Add multiple classes here...</div>
```